# Java - Could not find the main class - reinstall didn't work

Tags: java, eclipse

I got weird java error. When I try to run my code there appears window with:

> Could not find the main class..

I have tried to reinstall java, but it 
didn't help. Path to `/bin` directory is set properly. Can you help me ?

Comment: You might want to post something about your code.  It sounds like your directory structure is hosed.  Do you have this problem even creating brand new, clean app?

Comment: What is your main class and does it happen in every project?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18093928/what-does-could-not-find-or-load-main-class-mean

Answer (score 0):

It happened with friend before and the reason was selecting right jre within project setup stage.
When you setup your project be sure you selected your right JRE -> Use a project specific JRE :jre1.8.0_31 something like this.

Isupposed that you have main method , also you did not delete or miss up with your source files.